# PHP file upload (via Curl on the command line)

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a nightmare using PHP to upload files to my server, however when using this simple HTML form, it appears to work:

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploads.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

The PHP is then:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Is there any possible way to send a file via this technique using curl from the command line or a shell script?   i.e something along the lines of:

```
curl -f "@/path/to/my/file;type=text/html" http://mywebserver.com/uploads.php
```

That particular line gives me: "curl: (22) Failed to connect to ::1: Permission denied" although there is no password on the site etc.  I assume this is possible, but I'm getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: You should also set the method to post via `-X 'POST'`

Comment: Be very carefully with this script as it uploads any kind of files and is a security hole (scripts can be uploaded directly to your server and then executed using the browser)... so extra coding for protection is required!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want the argument to be a capital `F` (for Form). Lowercase `f` is for fail, and returns error code 22. Seriously, it's in the manual!

> -f, --fail
>
> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is
>   mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed
>   attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a
>   document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also
>   describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting
>   that and return error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where
>   non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when
>   authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).
>
> -F, --form
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has
>   pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the
>   Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables
>   uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a
>   file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content
>   part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The
>   difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in
>   the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get
>   the contents for that text field from a file.

Also, you've not named your file variable. I think you want:

```
curl -F "uploadedfile=@/path/to/my/file" http://mywebserver.com/uploads.php
```

Comment: Thanks, though it still doesn't work. (this time the PHP returns with: "there was an error uploading the file".  I think I'm destined to be a -f failure today.

Comment: I've added a bit about naming your file variable too

Comment: You Sir, are a genius!!  Thanks so much, very much appreciated.  Working like a dream.